# Excel 2013 64bit can't use Excel Add-in by DEPLOYTOOL [MATLAB]

Tags: matlab, 64-bit, office-2013

Recently I upgrade my Office to Office 2013(64bit) on Win8.1(64bit). But the add-in dll files can not be registered by "regsvr32.exe {dll path}", in the same way I can create Excel Add-in by using delploytool for Office 2010(64bit).

Anybody know how to make Excel 2013 (64bit) work with the Excel Add-in generated by DEPLOYTOOL?

Cheers,
Cross

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to use Office 32bit even if you are using Windows 64bit, because of compatibility issues with add-ins. Office 32bit is fully supported with Windows 64bit

Comment: I tried Office 2013(32bit) on a 64bit PC, still doesn't work. Same with Office 2013(64bit), namely can not find the dll(add-in) from VBA reference.

Answer (score 1):

If the dlls are 32 bit then, I'm afraid, you're out of luck: a 32 bit dll cannot be loaded into a 64 bit process. That's an operating system level constraint.

Your only option is to downgrade your Microsoft Office to 32 bit. Then you get your 32 bit `dll`s back. But to register them, you need to use the `regsvr32` executable in C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ (the normal place for the 32 bit compatibility programs). Then you can add references in the normal way.

Comment: I have been very careful about the consistence. Win 8.1, Matlab 2013a, Office 2013 are all 64bit; I only ever replaced Office 2013 with a 32bit version. But neither works.

Comment: Have you registered the 32 bit dll yet?

Comment: And Matlab 2013a on a Win 8.1 (64bit) will definitely created a 64bit dll. Because the Matlab deploytool/compiler rely on the system C++ compilers, which are all 64bit, if I am right.

Comment: setup exact same 32bit environment with Visual Studio Express 2010, winSDK 7.1, Matlab 2013a. And created a 32bit Excel Add-in dll. No matter which regsvr32.exe I use on a 64bit OS, they both returned an error: 
The module {dll path} may not compatible with the version of Windows that you're running......

So I think the issue is from the 64bit OS, while not the Office 2013 64bit.

Comment: have you looked at your dll using dependency viewer?

Comment: I did use DependencyWalker. Both 32bit dll and 64bit failed, however the 64bit one works for Office 2010 64bit and 32bit one works for Office 2010 32bit. So these two files even both failed with the dependency.exe, but this reason should be they are generated by Matlab with MCR runtime api's problem.

Comment: minor correction, this should also be Office 2013 64bit problem, because Office 2010 64bit in the same environment works.